# Overloading operators '=' and '+'

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

I'm learning how to use templates and how to overload operators. I've managed to overload `operator[]`, but I've encountered a problem with overloading `operator+` and `operator=`. Here is my code:

```
template <class T>
class A
{  
public:
    //...
    friend A<T>& A<T>::operator+ (A<T>&, const A<T>&);
    friend A<T>& A<T>::operator= (A<T>&, const A<T>&);
};

template<class T> A<T>& A<T>::operator+ (A<T>& left, const A<T>& right)
{
    //some functions
return left;
}

template<class T> A<T>& A<T>::operator= (A<T>& left, const A<T>& right)
{
    //some functions
    return left;
}
```

Whenver I try to compile, I get those errors:

> '+': is not a member of 'A<T>'
>
> '=': is not a member of 'A<T>'
>
> 'operator =' must be a non-static member

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:

I've managed to update the code:

```
template <class T>
class A
{  
public:
    //...
    A<T> operator+ (A<T>);
    A<T> operator= (A<T>, const A<T>);
};

template<class T> A<T> A<T>::operator+ (A<T> right)
{
    //some functions
    return *this;
}

template<class T> A<T> operator= (A<T> right)
{
    //some functions
    return *this;
}
```

Looks like `operator+` works now fine, but compiler gives this error:

> 'operator=' must be a non static member

Why is it a static member, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the `A<T>::` scope in the function definitions.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot. Template parameters are not _"inherited"_ to `friend` declarations. You have to declare them as `template<typename U> friend A<U>& operator+ (A<U>&, const A<U>&);`

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm getting now compiler's internal error :P
Nevermind, it now still produces the 'not member' errors :/

Comment: May be put `friend` first, but I'm a 100% sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters assignment operators must be non-static member functions

From the C++ Standard (13.5.3 Assignment )

> 1 **An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member
>   function** with exactly one parameter. Because a copy assignment
>   operator operator= is implicitly declared for a class if not declared
>   by the user (12.8), a base class assignment operator is always hidden
>   by the copy assignment operator of the derived class.

And secondly (11.3 Friends)

> 1 A friend of a class is a function or class that is given permission
>   to use the private and protected member names from the class. A class
>   specifies its friends, if any, by way of friend declarations. Such
>   declarations give special access rights to the friends, but they **do
>   not make the nominated friends members of the befriending class**.

Thus for example this definition

```
template<class T> A<T>& A<T>::operator+ (A<T>& left, const A<T>& right)
                        ^^^^^
{
//some functions
return left;
}
```

is incorrect. At least you should remove  `A<T>::` because the operator is not a member of the class.

Comment: Yeah, I totally forgot about it. So now I deleted the friend and 'A<T>::' but I'm still getting the last error, that operator= must be a non static member. How can I make it non static? Actually, I've looked at my operator[] definiton and there was also the same mistake, but for some reason compiler let me do this :P Now it also produces this 'non static member' error :C

Comment: @Executor1909 Read one more the quote from the Standard. The operator shall have only one parameter.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I changed that only to check if those previous errors would disappear, now they have only one parameter. 'Non static' error still occurs

Comment: @Executor1909 What is unclear? The operator shall be declared within the class definition and have not the friend specifier. What is the problem?

Comment: There's a compiler error saying that operator '=' must be a non static member.

Declaration looks now like this:
A<T> operator= (const A<T>&);
And definition:
template<class T> A<T> operator= (const A<T>& right)
{
    //some functions
    return *this;
}
I have no idea why it is still a static member.

Comment: @Executor1909 However the binary plus operator should be indeed declared like a friend function of the class and have two parameters.

Comment: @Executor1909 As it is a class member then you have to specify A<T>:: in the definition before the operator name.

Answer (score 0):

An operator that is implemented as a non-static member must accept only 1 input parameter, the right-hand operand.  The left-hand operand is the `this` object that the operator is being called on.

An operator that is implemented as a static member or a non-member must accept 2 input parameter, the left-hand and right-hand operands.

Your `operator=` is declared as a non-static member with 2 input parameters, which is wrong.

Also, `operator+` is meant to return a new object that is a copy of the two input objects added together.  Do not return a reference to the object that the operator is being called on.  Whereas `operator=` is meant to return a reference to the object that is being assigned to.

Try this:

```
template <class T>
class A
{  
public:
    //...
    A<T> operator+(const A<T>&) const;
    A<T>& operator=(const A<T>&);
};

template<class T> A<T> A<T>::operator+(const A<T>& right) const
{
    A<T> result(*this);
    //some functions to add right to result as needed...
    return result;
}

template<class T> A<T>& A<T>::operator=(const A<T>& right)
{
    // some functions to copy right into this...
    return *this;
}
```